# How to initialize a struct to NULL in cython?

Tags: cython

I have the following macro in a header file of a library I want to wrap:

```
#define RB_ROOT (struct rb_root) { NULL, }
```

The RB_ROOT macro seems to be used to initalize a root node with NULL in the C code. This is what the `rb_root` looks like:

```
struct rb_root {
    struct rb_node *rb_node;
};
```

I want to initialize a rb_root in Cython. This means that I need to create it and set it to NULL.

I have tried

```
self.root = ckerneltree.rb_root(node=NULL)
```

but this gives me the error

```
    cdef ckerneltree.rb_root root
    cdef ckerneltree.rb_node node

    def __cinit__(self):

        self.root = ckerneltree.rb_root(node=NULL)
                                            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kerneltree.pyx:10:45: Cannot assign type 'void *' to 'rb_node'
```

and if I remove the kwarg like so

```
self.root = ckerneltree.rb_root()
```

I get a C compiler warning which is irksome:

```
kerneltree.c: In function '__pyx_tp_new_10kerneltree_IntervalTree':
kerneltree.c:1100:22: warning: '__pyx_t_1.rb_node' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   __pyx_v_self->root = __pyx_t_1;
                      ^
kerneltree.c:1090:18: note: '__pyx_t_1.rb_node' was declared here
   struct rb_root __pyx_t_1;
                  ^
```

What is the correct way to do it?

---

Ps. this is what my .pxd looks like:

```
cdef extern from "src/rbtree.h":

    cdef struct rb_node:
        pass

    cdef struct rb_root:
        rb_node node
```

My .pyx:

```
cimport ckerneltree

cdef class IntervalTree:

    cdef ckerneltree.rb_root root

    def __cinit__(self):

        self.root = ckerneltree.rb_root()
```

Comment: I am not a C programmer (yet) so it would be neat if you could explain why I get the error `Cannot assign type 'void *' to 'rb_node'`. I am guessing that NULL has a more specific meaning in Cython than in C perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be surprising, but in your case `self.rb_root.node` is already set to `NULL`. However, if you want to set it to `NULL` explicitly you can do the following:

```
 cdef class IntervalTree:
    cdef ckerneltree.rb_root root

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.root.rb_root = NULL # setting pointer to NULL explicitly
```

This might be counter-intuitive for a Python coder, where everything is a reference, but `root` is not a pointer to an `rb_root`-object, but the object itself. This is what the definition of the cdef class `IntervalTree` looks like in C code:

```
struct __pyx_obj_4test_IntervalTree {
  PyObject_HEAD
  struct rb_root root;  
};
```

As you can see it is defined as `rb_root` and not `rb_root *`. The memory layout of an `IntervalTree`-object is quite simple:

```
      +-------------------+ +--------------------+
      |      PyObject     | |      rb_root       |
      +-------------------+ +--------------------+
      | Py-Obect members  | |      rb_node       |
      +-------------------+ +--------------------+
      |      ?? bytes     | |      8 bytes       |
      +-------------------+ +--------------------+
```

The default initialization of Python objects kicks in before `__cinit()__` is executed, and sets the whole memory of the object to `0`s, thus the 8 bytes for `rb_node` (which is a pointer to an `rb_node`-object) will have value `0`, which is the same as `NULL`. But there is no harm in initializing it explicitly.